# update selected documents with a new property

Tags: mongodb

This Meteor code is trying to add a new property to selected documents but failed to. Not sure why? Thanks

`DisplayCol.update({userId: Meteor.userId(), action: 'act1'}, {$set: {'prop1': true}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the way the following example is done:

```
 // return array of my messages
var myMessages = Messages.find({userId: Session.get('myUserId')}).fetch();

// create a new message
Messages.insert({text: "Hello, world!"});

// mark my first message as "important"
Messages.update(myMessages[0]._id, {$set: {important: true}});
```